# How can I find the number of times the basic operation is executed when given probability of successful search?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, search, code-analysis

[The Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUwqZ.png)

[This question (1-b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3W4W.png) is asking for the number of comparisons made by the algorithm above in the average case, given the probability of successful search, which is p (0<=p<=1).

All I understand is this: in the worst case scenario, the algorithm would make n+1 comparisons.

I don't understand the solution below.

[The solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muNv5.png)

Answer (score 0):

The number of comparisons made when a probability `p` is involved is

```
(1-p).f(n) + p.g(n)
```

Where

- `f(n)` is the number of operations in case of unsuccessful searches, which is the worst case complexity `1 + n`.
- `g(n)` is the expected number of operations in case of successful searches.

Assuming there is the same chance to find the searched key `K` at any index `i` of the array, the expectation of the number of operations `X` for each of the equiprobable cases is

```
g(n) = E(X) = 0/n + 1/n + ... + (n-1)/n + n/n = n/2
```

Therefore

```
(1-p).f(n) + p.g(n) = (1-p).n + p.(n-1)/2
                    = 1 + n - p.n/2
```

When `p = 0`, we find back the worst case complexity `n`.
When `p = 1`, the expected complexity is `1 + n/2`.

Answer (score 0):

You divide the average case in two parts:

1. The key is in the array: In this case the average number of comparisons is

   > (1+2+3+...+n)/n = (n+1)/2
2. The key is not in the array: In this case the number of comparisons is

   > n+1

Now, given the probability p that the key is in the array you can calculate the number of comparisons by

> p * (#comparisons if the key is in the array) + (1-p)*(#comparisons if the key is *not* in the array)

which yields

> p * [(n+1)/2] + (1-p)*(n+1)

which simplifies to

> (2-p)(n+1)/2

Comment: Because you want to have the average. If the key is in the first position you nees 1 comparison, if the key is in the secon position you need 2 comparisons and so on. If you compute the average over all possibilities you have to divide by n.